# SharePoint List: Exclude Top 1 Descending (Hide the most recent entry)

Tags: sharepoint

I have a SharePoint list displaying twice on a page. The top view of the list shows the most recent entry (descending, top 1). I have the same list below that, formatted to appear differently, displaying all the other entries. I'd like to have the lower list display descending, but exclude the Top 1 (descending, 2-n).

Is that possible within the controls of SharePoint classic?

I had some ideas, #1 which is a kludge - I want it to be seamless - and some are hypothetical, so don't even know if possible.

1. Add a column called archive (Yes/No), so that only items marked Yes appear in the lower list
2. Use Javascript to exclude the top item in the list
3. A function in the web part properties to limit the descending list to 2-n, excluding the top 1

Answer (score 0):

Based on your second list view, you could hide specific row by CSR(insert script editor webpart into the page and insert script into script editor webpart).

Just sample to change the first row of second list view.

```
<script ype="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
            OnPostRender: [
                function (ctx) {
                    if (ctx.view == "{E0F2B303-87C0-48BB-A806-1C641049882D}") {
                        var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
                        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                            var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
                            var row = document.getElementById(rowId);
                            if (i == 0) {
                                row.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                                //hide
                                //row.style.display = "none";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        });

    })();
</script>
```

[image]

[More about CSR](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views)

Comment: Sorry about the delay, will try it out today.

Comment: This did not work for me. The problem is that I am not using a bare list, but a Content Rollup Query in a page, rather than jut a view.